# Unable to get Network IP Address in React Native

Tags: react-native, ip

So, I need to get the User's network IPV4 Address. This is my following code and the attempted Libraries that I used for fetching the IPV4 Address. None of them are working.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Network from 'expo-network';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import { NetworkInfo } from "react-native-network-info";
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import publicIP from 'react-native-public-ip';

const App = () => {
  const [ipAddress, setIPAddress] = useState('');


  //react-native-network-info
  NetworkInfo.getIPV4Address().then(ipv4Address => {
    console.log(ipv4Address);
    setIPAddress(ipv4Address);
  });


  //react-native-device-info
  const getIpAddress = async () => {
    const ip = await DeviceInfo.getIpAddress();
    console.log(ip);
    setIPAddress(ip);
  };


  //react-native-public-ip
  publicIP()
    .then(ip => {
    console.log(ip);
    setIPAddress(ip);
    });


  //@react-native-community/netinfo
  NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
  });


  //axios
  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
    console.log(res.data);
    setIPAddress(res.data.IPv4)
  };


  //expo-network
  const ipAlert = async () => {
    const ip = await Network.getIpAddressAsync()
    setIPAddress(ip);
  };


  return (
     <View style={{ top: 200 }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20 }}>{ipAddress}</Text>
        <Button title='GET IP' onPress={getIpAddress} />
     </View>
   )
};

export default App;
```

As you can see my code I have tried all the possibilities.
When I run the code, I either get the Public IP Address or an error

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
> A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

Any Help is Appreciated.
:)

FYI- I tried each one separately, not all together.

Answer (score 0):

i fond there is AppRegistry issue from your given error.

so you have to check root **index.js** file. and check the imported path of **App.js** which is highlighted in below example and replace actual path of app.js.

example:

```
index.js

     import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
     import App from './App'
```

**import App from './App';** check this path

```
  import {name as appName} from './app.json';      
  AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

/

```
 App.js
    

        import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import publicIP from 'react-native-public-ip';
    
    export default App = () => {
    
      useState(() => {
        publicIP()
          .then(ip => {
            console.log(ip);
            // '47.122.71.234'
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            // 'Unable to get IP address.'
          });
      }, [])
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>App</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

package is working in my code.

Comment: Just did what you said, but it shows the External IP Address that the ISP provides. What I am searching for is the Internal IP Address that you get when running 'Ipconfig' in your CMD.
Do you have anything that might help with that.

Comment: sorry for delay,

i got your point. for that you can use "react-native-network-info" package where you can get device local ip. if my ans is help full for you so plz give vote to my ans.

link is https://github.com/pusherman/react-native-network-info

worked for me.

Comment: As you can see in my code I tried using react-native-network-info. I also mentioned the error that I am getting after running the code. I thought maybe my project was broken or something, so I created a new fresh project and tried in that, but it still gave me the same error.